# Creating a hard page flip effect

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, page-flipping

There are several page flipping source codes out there. Here are just a few I already looked at:

- http://pageflip.hu/pageflip2/pageflip_v225_source.php
- https://github.com/nidin/as3-flip-book
- http://www.rubenswieringa.com/code/as3/flex/Book/source/
- http://www.megazine3.de/home.en.html

However, none of them really satisfy my needs. I don't need any page curl effects, all I want is the hard cover effect, but for all pages.
Are there any other examples out there that have the hard page flip effect on all pages? Or are there any documentation on how the matrix transformation of a cover page works - since I don't quite get it?
The content of the album will consist of video, audio, and images.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You dont need any of these libraries for a hard-cover effect as they usually focus on the curling. Simply use the built-in-feature:
rotationY
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html#rotationY

Comment: Ah. Yes, that was the effect I was looking for. Thought there might be some libs out there, where I only have to add contents to it. This way I would have to add a lot of code to actually get the desired book effect (e.g. when at the end of the book, and someone clicks a bookmark of the beginning, previous pages should be flipped until it reaches the desired page). Thanks nonetheless!

Comment: Managed to create the desired effects with greensock in combination with rotationY. Great!

Answer (score 1):

In this library:
http://www.rubenswieringa.com/code/as3/flex/Book/source/ 
`Page` class has property `hard`. If set `true` for it than a page will become hard. You may set this property for each page. For example, look at his method:

```
        private function toggleHard (page:Page):void {
            hard_btn.toolTip = (page.hard) ? "make next page hard" : "make next page fluid";
            hardBtnIcon = (page.hard) ? hardBtnIcon1 : hardBtnIcon2;
            page.hard = !page.hard;
            hard_btn.invalidateDisplayList();
        }
```

Comment: Hmm. Ok. I was actually looking for someting I can use in Flash IDE, but I will take a closer look at this Flex solution.